# Spring Boot - Hikari Database Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

Recently worked on migrating code to Spring Boot 2.x and am running into an issue configuring the datasource bean. We have two datasources and so we are building the DataSource beans by hand using a DataSourceBuilder.

Per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) , I am setting these properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

However, when I do that I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1059) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
```

If I change my settings to do this:

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
```

then it works.

It also works for a single datasource if I comment out the bean that creates the datasource explicitly which leads me to believe there's a problem in the datasourcebuilder code.

An example repository with just a single data source showing the issue is available here: https://github.com/azizabah/hikari-issue

So what changed between SB 1.5.X and SB 2.X from a configuration stand point when having multiple data sources?

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - added edit with question at bottom.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing the configuration of DataSourceProperties and directly trying to wire it.

You need to follow the following documentation to achieve what you want to do in first place :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Co-incidentally somebody did same mistake and raised as bug in git, if you want you can see the same documentation getting referred  as solution:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12758

Comment: Please provide the solution within your answer, links should only be used for supporting information or further details. An answer should not be "you're doing it wrong, look on this link how to fix this".

Comment: @jazz - went ahead and marked as answer although it would have been nice to call out that this is a change from how you could do it in SB 1.5.X.